# Spring and SimpleMailMessage: change setTo and setFrom

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail

I am building a Spring app that allows the user to send an email to customer support.
I have noticed though that it doesn't matter what I put in the attributes "*setTo*" and "*setFrom*" of the SimpleMailMessage, I keep receiving the email from myself to myself.

Here is my code:

Controller Endpoint

```
@PostMapping("/send-email")
public ResponseEntity<Object> sendEmail(@RequestParam String userEmail) {
    log.info("[START] send-email");
    notificationService.sendNotification();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Service

```
 public void sendNotification(String emailUtente) {
    SimpleMailMessage messaggio = new SimpleMailMessage();
    messaggio.setTo(customerServiceAddress);
    messaggio.setFrom(emailUtente);
    messaggio.setSubject("Test Spring Email");
    messaggio.setText("Tadaaaa! Email da Spring!");
    try{
        javaMailSender.send(messaggio);
    } catch (Exception ex){
        log.error("Error! " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=theCustomerServiceAddress
spring.mail.password=thePassword
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Where am I mistaking?

Also, I am not sure what should be put into the property *spring.mail.username*, I guessed the email address of whom is receiving the email?

Thank you for your experience and time.

Comment: You need to use an email account to be able to send email. In your case spring.mail.username should contain the email address of your gmail account used to send emails.

Comment: Thank you Atimene. In case the sender shall be the user, how do I proceed?

Comment: In your case you are using the same email address to configure and to send to. it's normal that you got the same sender and receiver. The property spring.mail.username is independent from the setTo and setFrom methods. this property is only used to configure your mail server.

Comment: You're right about the "setTo" attribute, though the setFrom one is beeing replaced by the _spring.email.username_